# How can I throw an exception in Clojure?

Tags: exception, clojure, functional-programming

I wish to throw an exception and have the following:

```
(throw "Some text")
```

However it seems to be ignored.

Comment: `throw` throws instances of Java `Throwable`. Does `(throw (Exception. "Some text"))` work?

Comment: when I try (throw "Some text") I get a ClassClassException because String cannot be cast to Throwable. So it's odd that the throw is being "ignored" in your case....

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to wrap your string in a [Throwable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html):

```
(throw (Throwable. "Some text"))
```

or

```
(throw (Exception. "Some text"))
```

You can set up a try/catch/finally block as well:

```
(defn myDivision [x y]
  (try
    (/ x y)
    (catch ArithmeticException e
      (println "Exception message: " (.getMessage e)))
    (finally 
      (println "Done."))))
```

REPL session:

```
user=> (myDivision 4 2)
Done.
2
user=> (myDivision 4 0)
Exception message:  Divide by zero
Done.
nil
```

Answer (score 10):

[clojure.contrib.condition](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/condition-api.html) provides a Clojure-friendly means of handling exceptions. You can raise conditons with causes. Each condition can have its own handler.

There are a number of examples in the [source on github](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib/blob/b8d2743d3a89e13fc9deb2844ca2167b34aaa9b6/src/examples/clojure/clojure/contrib/condition/example.clj).

It's quite flexible, in that you can provide your own key, value pairs when raising and then decide what to do in your handler based on the keys/values.

E.g. (mangling the example code):

```
(if (something-wrong x)
  (raise :type :something-is-wrong :arg 'x :value x))
```

You can then have a handler for `:something-is-wrong`:

```
(handler-case :type
  (do-non-error-condition-stuff)
  (handle :something-is-wrong
    (print-stack-trace *condition*)))
```

Comment: Now it is replaced with [slingshot](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot) (taken from [Where Did Clojure.Contrib Go](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go))

Answer (score 10):

If you want to throw an exception and include some debugging info in it (in addition to a message string), you can use the built-in [ex-info](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ex-info) function.

To extract the data from the previously-constructed ex-info object, use [ex-data](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ex-data).

Example from clojuredocs:

```
(try
  (throw 
    (ex-info "The ice cream has melted!" 
       {:causes             #{:fridge-door-open :dangerously-high-temperature} 
        :current-temperature {:value 25 :unit :celcius}}))
  (catch Exception e (ex-data e))
```

In a comment kolen mentioned [slingshot](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot), which provides advanced functionality that allows you not only to throw objects of arbitrary type (with throw+), but also use a more flexible catch syntax to inspect data inside thrown objects (with try+). Examples from [the project repo](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot#usage):

tensor/parse.clj

```
(ns tensor.parse
  (:use [slingshot.slingshot :only [throw+]]))

(defn parse-tree [tree hint]
  (if (bad-tree? tree)
    (throw+ {:type ::bad-tree :tree tree :hint hint})
    (parse-good-tree tree hint)))
```

math/expression.clj

```
(ns math.expression
  (:require [tensor.parse]
            [clojure.tools.logging :as log])
  (:use [slingshot.slingshot :only [throw+ try+]]))

(defn read-file [file]
  (try+
    [...]
    (tensor.parse/parse-tree tree)
    [...]
    (catch [:type :tensor.parse/bad-tree] {:keys [tree hint]}
      (log/error "failed to parse tensor" tree "with hint" hint)
      (throw+))
    (catch Object _
      (log/error (:throwable &throw-context) "unexpected error")
      (throw+))))
```